# The meaning of "宝藏"?

Tags: translation, meaning

I know that "宝藏" can mean "underground mineral deposits", but it can also mean "treasures".

My question is this: In addition to the two definitions above, can "宝藏" also mean a location that stores treasures, such as a "treasure trove"? Or is that definition only restricted for something like "宝库"?

The reason being is that since "宝" is treasure, and "藏" is hide, I get the feeling that it is "hiding the treasure", aka. a place to hide treasure, meaning a treasure trove. Or perhaps it just means "the treasure that should be hid"? Quite unsure on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

藏 has two meanings:

- as a verb (cáng), it can mean *to hide, to conceal*, etc.
- as a noun (zàng), it can mean *depository*, such as 宝藏 (bǎozàng).

Of course the two meanings are related.

To get an impression what this word means, search for 宝藏 on [Google Image search](https://www.google.hu/search?q=%E5%AE%9D%E8%97%8F&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIjseGjPaoxwIVwmsUCh3vgA0K&biw=1366&bih=673) or [Baidu Image search](http://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E5%AE%9D%E8%97%8F).

Answer (score -1):

How about this from iciba?

温莎城堡确实是名副其实的古物宝藏。They translate:

Windsor Castle is quite literally an antique treasure trove.

There you go, 'treasure trove'! God shave the Queen!